# Java sphere volume calculation

Tags: java, volume, calculator

I have a Java class and im stumped on this issue. We have to make a volume calculator. You input the diamater of a sphere, and the program spits out the volume. It works fine with whole numbers but whenever I throw a decimal at it, it crashes. Im assuming it has to do with the precision of the variable

```
double sphereDiam;
double sphereRadius;
double sphereVolume;

System.out.println("Enter the diamater of a sphere:");
sphereDiam = keyboard.nextInt();
sphereRadius = (sphereDiam / 2.0);
sphereVolume = ( 4.0 / 3.0 ) * Math.PI * Math.pow( sphereRadius, 3 );
System.out.println("The volume is: " + sphereVolume);
```

So, like I said if i put in a whole number, it works fine. But I put in 25.4 and it crashes on me.

Comment: Ummm... doesn't nextInt() parse only integers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `keyboard.nextInt()` is expecting an `int`, not a `float` or `double`. You can change it to:

```
float sphereDiam;
double sphereRadius;
double sphereVolume;

System.out.println("Enter the diamater of a sphere:");
sphereDiam = keyboard.nextFloat();
sphereRadius = (sphereDiam / 2.0);
sphereVolume = ( 4.0 / 3.0 ) * Math.PI * Math.pow( sphereRadius, 3 );
System.out.println("The volume is: " + sphereVolume);
```

`nextFloat()` and `nextDouble()` will pickup `int` types as well and automatically convert them to the desired type.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to stick with doubles, you can call `nextDouble()` and keep `sphereDiam` a `double`.

Comment: Thanks so much! It's funny I tried that before and it didn't work. I must have typed it in wrong. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

```
double sphereDiam;
double sphereRadius;
double sphereVolume;
System.out.println("Enter the diameter of a sphere:");
sphereDiam = keyboard.nextDouble();
sphereRadius = (sphereDiam / 2.0);
sphereVolume = ( 4.0 / 3.0 ) * Math.PI * Math.pow( sphereRadius, 3 );
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("The volume is: " + sphereVolume);
```

Comment: Don't just paste working code as an answer. Explain what the problem is with OP's code and how he can fix that, then (if neccessary) you can also put working code into your answer.